# A problem with teams

Tags: combinatorics

From 7 people, we will make 7 teams, each with 3 people.  Each person will play on 3 different teams, and none of the seven people will have any "repeat" teammates. That is, if A and B are on one team together, then they must not be placed together on any other teams together.

One possible set of teams (labeling the people 1-7) satisfying these conditions is as follows:

{1,2,3}
{1,4,5}
{1,6,7}
{2,4,6}
{2,5,7}
{3,4,7}
{3,5,6}

Suppose we then try to generalize this problem.  From $n$ people we wish to make $n$ teams, each with $k$ people.  Each person will play on $k$ teams, and there should be no repeat teammates.  For at least some values of $n$ and $k$, (e.g. 7 and 3), solutions exists.  But for other combinations of values, none exist.  Consider $n=6$ and $k=3$, for instance.  Without loss of generality, let the first team be {1,2,3}.  Player 1 must then play on two other teams, without player 2 or player 3.  So let the second team be {1,4,5}.  But now we are stuck:  there is no way to make a third team involving player 1 because there is only one player with whom he has not yet played.

My question is this:  is there a necessary and sufficient condition on  $n$ and $k$ such that a solution to the problem exists?

Comment: What you are describing is a balanced incomplete block design (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockDesign.html) where $b=v$, $k=r$, and $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Thanks!  That is exactly it.  For others who may read this, my particular case is a symmetric balanced incomplete block design.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is a BIBD with parameters $b=n$, $v=n$, $k=k$, $r=k$, and $\lambda = 1$. A necessary condition for such a BIBD with parameters $(b,v,k,r,\lambda)$ to exist is to have the equality
$$\lambda(v-1) = r(k-1). $$
In this case, we must have
$$1(n-1) = k(k-1)\implies n = k(k-1)+1.$$
Hence, a necessary condition for your teams to exist is to have $n = k(k-1)+1$.

---

I had previously posted a partially sufficient condition, but it was written in error. This section has now been removed.

Comment: According to your scheme, for the case $n=7, k = 3$, my calculations give $B_{1,1}=\{v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{1,3}\}$ and $B_{1,2}=\{v_{1,1},v_{2,2},v_{1,3}\}$.  Since $v_{1,1}$ and $v_{1,3}$ appear on both teams, we have a violation of the parameters, no?

Comment: @Chad Actually, $B_{1,2} = \{v_{1,1},v_{2,2},v_{3,3}\}$.

Comment: You specified that the first index $h+(l-1)(j-1)$ is to be taken modulo $k-1=2$, such that it is an integer between $1$ and $k-1=2$, inclusive.  How then can the first index be $3$?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I mixed up columns and rows somewhere. One sec..

Comment: @Chad you are right; the proof does not work at all. I will remove that part...

Comment: Still get an upvote for the necessary condition, but I'm hopeful to make some progress in sufficiency before choosing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Joey Zou pointed out, this problem is an instance of a balanced incomplete block design (BIBD).

According to [this article](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387954875-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-101851-p9775353), page 5, "One of the main goals of combinatorial design theory is to determine necessary
and sufficient conditions for the existence of a (v, k, λ)-BIBD. This is a
very difficult problem in general, and there are many parameter sets where
the answer is not yet known."